# Can I use the 'pyttsx3' module and 'speech_recognition' module in an apk of my android app?

Tags: python, android, kivy, apk, pyttsx3

**Question - Can I use the 'pyttsx3' module and 'speech_recognition' module in an apk of my Android app? Are the 2 libraries compatible with Android?**

Actually, I am working on an AI with python, so for that I'll be needing these 2 libraries for the development of AI with kivy on Android OS.

here's the Kivy code :

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import pyttsx3

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        btn = Button(text = "Activate", size_hint = (.10,.20))
        btn.bind(on_press = self.callback)
        return btn
    def callback(self, event):
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        engine.setProperty("rate", 130)
        engine.say("Hello Sir!")
        engine.runAndWait()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Do you have Linux like Ubuntu ? ( if no then maybe can try to use virtual machine or windows subsystem for Linux ) Maybe you can try packaging it using Buildozer to see if it works.